# Why can't I use multithreading in my project?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mingw, clion

I want to start with multithreading, but my clion IDE (v. 2019.3.6) does not recognize created threads.
I also try to use threads from boost library, but there is also common error ("undefined reference to boost::threads" is there). I use c++14 in my clion and mingw compilator.

I compiled boost library using g++.

Code I try to run:

```
#include <iostream>       // std::cout

#include <boost/thread.hpp>

void foo(){
    // do stuff...
}

void bar(int x){
    // do stuff...
}

int main(){
    boost::thread t1(bar, 1);
    t1.join();

    return 0;
}
```

or:

```
#include <iostream>       // std::cout

#include <thread>

void foo(){
    // do stuff...
}

void bar(int x){
    // do stuff...
}

int main(){
    std::thread t1(bar, 1);
    t1.join();

    return 0;
}
```

errors which it generates:

```
CMakeFiles\client.dir/objects.a(client.cpp.obj): In function `boost::thread::start_thread()':
C:/boost_builded_from_sources/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:182: undefined reference to `boost::thread::start_thread_noexcept()'
CMakeFiles\client.dir/objects.a(client.cpp.obj): In function `boost::thread::~thread()':
C:/boost_builded_from_sources/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:257: undefined reference to `boost::thread::detach()'
CMakeFiles\client.dir/objects.a(client.cpp.obj): In function `boost::thread::join()':
C:/boost_builded_from_sources/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:759: undefined reference to `boost::thread::get_id() const'
C:/boost_builded_from_sources/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:759: undefined reference to `boost::this_thread::get_id()'
C:/boost_builded_from_sources/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:762: undefined reference to `boost::thread::join_noexcept()'
CMakeFiles\client.dir/objects.a(client.cpp.obj): In function `boost::detail::thread_data<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(int), boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<int> > > >::~thread_data()':
C:/boost_builded_from_sources/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:94: undefined reference to `boost::detail::thread_data_base::~thread_data_base()'
CMakeFiles\client.dir/objects.a(client.cpp.obj):client.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZTVN5boost6detail16thread_data_baseE[.refptr._ZTVN5boost6detail16thread_data_baseE]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for boost::detail::thread_data_base'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\client.dir\build.make:86: client.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:75: CMakeFiles/client.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:82: CMakeFiles/client.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:117: client] Error 2
```

or errors thread from std::thread

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\client\client.cpp: In function 'int main()':
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\client\client.cpp:15:10: error: 'thread' is not a member of 'std'
     std::thread t1(bar, 1);
          ^~~~~~
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\client\client.cpp:15:10: note: 'std::thread' is defined in header '<thread>'; did you forget to '#include <thread>'?
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\client\client.cpp:5:1:
+#include <thread>
 
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\client\client.cpp:15:10:
     std::thread t1(bar, 1);
          ^~~~~~
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\client\client.cpp:16:5: error: 't1' was not declared in this scope
     t1.join();
     ^~
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\client\client.cpp:16:5: note: suggested alternative: 'tm'
     t1.join();
     ^~
     tm
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\client.dir\build.make:63: CMakeFiles/client.dir/client.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:75: CMakeFiles/client.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:82: CMakeFiles/client.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:117: client] Error 2
```

Why thread is not memeber of std::thread?
I have attached proper header

Is this possible that mingw does not support multithreading?

Maybe someone had problem like this and will be able to help.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: How are you building your code?

Comment: "undefined reference to `boost::thread::start_thread_noexcept()'" means that you have not configured your project to link in the Boost library. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with the clion IDE, so I can't tell you how to fix that, but maybe knowing what the message means can help you to find the answer in the documentation. (Assuming nobody else answers before I finish typing this.)

Answer (score 0):

The mingw didn't recognize thread library.
I changed version of compilator to another and everything works nice.